# Querying XML data (attribute) in Sql Server

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012, xquery

I have some XML in an Xml-column in Sql Server that I would like to provide a view on top on. Specifically, I would like to expose the "version" attribute of the root element alongside the entire XML-chunk itself.

The table has a single column named "Tree".

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ClassificationTree xmlns="http://schemas.tempuri.org/2014/02/17" version="1.0">
  <Classification name="WTG" priority="1">
    <Classification name="Corrective" priority="1">
      <Classification name="RDSPP-Codes" priority="1" />
    </Classification>
    <Classification name="Predetermined" priority="2">
      <Classification name="Non Service related (tests, visits etc)" priority="1" />
      <Classification name="Scheduled Service" priority="2" />
    </Classification>
  </Classification>
</ClassificationTree>
```

When I query it like this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.tempuri.org/2014/02/17' AS ns1)
select 
  Tree.value('(/ns1:ClassificationTree/@version)[0]','varchar(20)') as Version
  , Tree 
from 
  ClassificationTree
```

I get the Xml-chunk all right, but the "version"-column is NULL.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes in XQuery start at 1 and not 0. I would suggest first trying to replace from within your query:

```
(/ns1:ClassificationTree/@version)[0]
```

to:

```
(/ns1:ClassificationTree/@version)[1]
```

However what you probably meant was -

```
/ns1:ClassificationTree[1]/@version
```

As you want to take the version attribute from the first ClassificationTree. What you were doing is retrieving all versions of all ClassificationTrees and then selecting the first (or you would have been if you used `[1]` and not `[0]`) which is much less efficient.

Comment: +1 for the explanation but the SQL Server implementation actually makes the first one faster to execute.

Comment: SQL Server uses a table valued function to find the first occurrence (using top) and in the first version that function is executed once to find the value and in the second it is executed first once to find the node and then a second time to find the attribute value.